# How do I switch between users, without logging out?

Tags: users, lightdm, display-manager, xscreensaver

I am using Lubuntu, my desktop environment is lxQt and screensaver is xScreensaver.

I'm trying to figure out a way to switch between users, (e.g. when pressing `meta + L`).

Even though, it is possible to lock the screen with xscreensaver, I'm unable to use "new login" button and it shows this message:

> could not excute "gdmflexiserver": No such file or directory

**Update 1**

I have come up with something I judge to be a hacky solution: creating a keyboard shortcut that triggers `dm-tool switch-to-greeter`.

Although, as I said: it's more like a hack than a solution. It also makes me authenticate twice: once for LightDM and another for XScreenSaver, which is not very convenient.

Comment: Do you want a whole desktop environment with the second user, or is it enough to run a window or two with the second user (within the desktop environment of the first user)?

Comment: @sudodus I want to something like in Windows 10. You hit `winkey + L`, then you're taken to the login screen which works as a lockscreen and user switcher. I want to do this, so I can isolate work profile from personal profile.

Comment: Which version of Lubuntu are you running (20.04 LTS or 20.10)? Have you considered creating a hotkey shortcut?

Comment: I tested right now, and **if you switch to Xubuntu, you can switch between users by default (there is an option in the logout window)**. If I remember correctly it should be possible to install `xubuntu-desktop` into Lubuntu (but you cannot remove it easily, if you change your mind). And then, if you log in 'as Xubuntu', you will get that option when logging out. - I don't know an easy way to do what you want in Lubuntu. I hope someone else can help you ...